Not able to perform read and write operation in iCloud in .Net Maui Mac
I have set up the app identifier in Apple developer with the document URL set up for iCloud and also updated the info.plist and entitlements according to this.
info.plist
<key>NSUbiquitousContainers</key>
<dict>
    <key>iCloud.com.abc.MyApp</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSUbiquitousContainerIsDocumentScopePublic</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSUbiquitousContainerName</key>
        <string>MyApp</string>
        <key>NSUbiquitousContainerSupportedFolderLevels</key>
        <string>Any</string>
    </dict>
</dict>

<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>

<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
<true/>

<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>fetch</string>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>

<key>NSUbiquitousContainersUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app uses iCloud containers to store and sync documents.</string>

Entitlement.plist
<key>com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers</key>
    <array>
        <string>iCloud.com.abc.MyApp</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.icloud-services</key>
    <array>
        <string>CloudDocuments</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers</key>
    <array>
        <string>iCloud.com.abc.MyApp</string>
    </array>

// Then I am using iCloud CRUD operation in app
// Code snippet
private void DeleteFolderFromICloud()
    {
        try {
            var iCloudDocumentsURL = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetUrlForUbiquityContainer(null);
            if (iCloudDocumentsURL != null)
            {
                var path = iCloudDocumentsURL.ToString().Replace("%C3%97", "x");
                var filepath = path.Replace("file://", string.Empty).Replace("%20", " ");
                var destinationdirectoryPath = filepath;
                if (Directory.Exists(destinationdirectoryPath))
                {
                    Directory.Delete(destinationdirectoryPath, recursive: true);
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            LogHandler.LogError(ex);
        }
    }

But in Delete operation gives Exception -> System.IO.IOException: Access to the path '/Users/USERABC/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~abc~MyApp/' is denied.


Are you testing on a real device or a simulator? 2. In the Info.plist file ensure the Bundle Identifier matches the Bundle ID set when creating an App ID; The iOS Bundle Signing uses a Provisioning Profile that contain an App ID with the iCloud App Service, and the Custom Entitlements file selected.



No, I am building on my MAC. 2. The Bundle Identifier matches the Bundle ID in the info.plist file. 3. Provisioning profile contains app ID with iCloud service enabled for the iCloud Document service type.


You must use a device to test the iCloud. And this could be a potential issue on Apple side, I noticed that you've logged it on Apple Develop Forum:https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/751248, you can follow up there.
